# How to override react-bootstrap colors?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I was looking up how to change it but none of the solutions seemed to work for me.

I want to override the color of a react-bootstrap button.

This solution as below works just fine and is exactly what i wanna do:

```
<Button
   block
   style={{backgroundColor: '#0B0C10', borderColor: '#45A293', color: '#45A293', borderRadius: '100px'}}
>
   sample text
</Button>
```

But i don't wanna rewrite it each time i use button so i would like to have solution with css, I've tried using this:

```
.custom-button {
    background-color: #1F2833;
    border-color: #45A293;
    border: 3px solid-transparent;
    color: #45A293;
    border-radius: 100px;
}
```

And then passing it in className like like so className="custom-button" but it doesn't really work.

I am using Button from react-bootstrap

```
import {Button} from "react-bootstrap";
```

Styles from bootstrap

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Using versions as below:

```
"react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
"bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
```

Answer (score 2):

Styles applied using the `style=""` attribute of HTML elements are more **specific** than styles applied through classes, which is why your first solution worked. Appending `!important` at the end of styles is one way of overriding other styles which are more specific than `.custom-button` class.

One quick solution that comes to my mind, that will ensure that you don't repeat yourself, is storing the styles in an object and importing them from a file.

styles.js

```
const styles = {
    customButton: {
        backgroundColor: '#0B0C10',
        borderColor: '#45A293',
        color: '#45A293',
        borderRadius: '100px'
    }
};

export default styles;
```

Component.jsx

```
import { styles }  from './styles.js'

<Button
   block
   style={styles.customButton}
>
   sample text
</Button>
```

Otherwise you would have to play with attaching ID's or construct more specific css selectors.

Comment: Since i wanted to change every button to look like it i worked it around with #root Button { styles here } style.

Comment: @miyavmiyav consider accepting or up voting the answer if it led to a solution.

Comment: It didnt tho so won't do that.

Comment: So are you implying the above solution is not a working solution? Or the advice given at the end that nudges you to use CSS ID selector (since it's more specific) is different from what you ended up doing?

Comment: The advice at the end i read on each and every css question i searched still didnt provide an example on how to use it, and i ended up with solution that changes every Button inside Root id which is every button in my react application. Also its not about what works or not like your first solution. I'd still have to write it with each component and each button inside of it so that is still not a solution that satisfies me.

Comment: If you read the solution carefully, the styles object is exported from a file, then imported in the component with the button in question. Which means the only thing you would have to "write it with each component and each button inside of it " is the import statement `import { styles }  from './styles.js'` and the style attribute on the element `style={styles.customButton}`

Comment: I see that still you have to write it inline in each button style={styles.customButton} ... And writing it inside each button is not the solution i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Add a bg or btn

```
.bg-custom-button {
    background-color: #1F2833;
    border-color: #45A293;
    border: 3px solid-transparent;
    color: #45A293;
    border-radius: 100px;
}
```

Got mine working like that

Then in the `bg="custom-button"`

Comment: i was providing the solution that i was searching for in here ;c

Comment: I don't understand the last line:  Then in the bg="custom-button"

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if this effect is intended or not but the easiest way that I have found to override React Bootstrap css is to use Material ui withStyles. Here is an example.

```
import React from 'react';

import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import ButtonGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ButtonGroup';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

const styles = {
    logoContainer: {
        position: 'fixed',
    },
    rowStyles: {
        marginBottom: '10px',
    },
    button: {
        border: '3px inset #ffc107',
        borderRadius: '50%',
        width: '55px',
        height: '55px',
        fontFamily: 'fangsong',
        fontSize: '1em', 
        fontWeight: '700',
        color: 'white',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(0,0,0, 0.5)',
    }
}

const Logo = (props) => {     
    const logoStyles = props.classes;
    return (
    <div>
    <Container container='true' className={logoStyles.logoContainer}>
        <ButtonGroup >            
            <Col>
                <Row className={logoStyles.rowStyles}>
                    <Button onClick={{}} className={logoStyles.button}>BS</Button>
                </Row>
            </Col>            
        </ButtonGroup> 
    </Container>
    </div>
);                           
                    }

export default withStyles(styles)(Logo);
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "bsPrefix" prop which allows to override the underlying component CSS base class name.
bsPrefix="custom-button"